# Can I add user accounts to Windows Server 2012 based on Microsoft accounts?

Tags: login, user-accounts, windows-server-2012

Windows 8 lets me create user accounts simply by the email address of a Microsoft account (aka Windows Live account).  Is there someway to activate such a facility in the Windows Server 2012 SKU?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is not a way to add Windows Live accounts to Server 2012.

You can add some of the client features via the Desktop Experience sub-feature under User Interfaces and Infrastructure, but Windows Live authentication is not part of that feature set.

Are you looking at running the server OS as a client machine?

UPDATE:
If you are looking to have some sort of shared management structure, you may want to look at creating a domain and associating the domain accounts used on your Windows 8 boxes with a Live ID (to get all the settings synchronization that provides).  Then you can assign perms via the domain.

Comment: I can't speak for the OP, but personally I have an instance of Server 2012 running at home, and would like to set up file-shares and limit the permissions based on Microsoft Live user accounts.

Comment: @BTownTKD I updated my answer with an option for that, but you can't (in any way I've found) grant rights directly to a live id from Windows Server.